# Tensorflow 2.4.1 - Couldn't invoke ptxas.exe

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I try to run Tensorflow with GPU support (GTX 1660 SUPER).

I created an enviroment using anaconda, than installed `cudatoolkit` (version `11.0.221`) and `tensorflow-gpu` (version `2.4.1`). Afterwards, I downloaded `cuDNN` (version `8.0.4`), and copied all files from cuDNN's `bin` folder to my environment's bin folder at `anaconda3\envs\<env name>\Library\bin`.
In my script, I've set the memory limit to my GPU's memory using `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`.

When I run the script (which uses convolutional algorithms), I get a warning that says `Couldn't invoke ptxas.exe --version` which comes after an `Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2` error.
After the launch failure, I get: `Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.  Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.`

I've already tried switching to cuDNN version `8.1.1`.

How I fix this?

Comment: You can't really fix it. The problem is that your GPU is too new for the hardware profiles which the tensorflow developers build into the packages they distribute. The message is just telling you that JIT compilation is happening because there is no native binary for your GPU. The only thing to do is wait for them to catch up

Comment: Right afterward I get an error that says `tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2`. Is it related?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I’m getting the same error with gtx 970.

Comment: Try workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33375#issuecomment-543634440). Thanks!

Comment: Running into same problem. Here is my environment details: tensorflow-gpu=2.4.0, cudnn=8.0.5.39, cudatoolkit=11.0.221

Comment: Solved by using tensorflow=2.3, cudnn=7.6.5 and cudatoolkit=10.1

Comment: Why is this actually a problem & what does it influence?

Answer (score 11):

I got a new fix for this.

First I tried using `tensorflow=2.3, cudnn=7.6.5 and cudatoolkit=10.1` as mentioned in previous answers. However, every time I put a model to train, the process was going stale and the training seemed to be stuck in epoch 1.

I then managed to include ptxas in my conda environment by running `conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc` The packages I am using are:

```
tensorflow=2.9, cudnn=8.1.0, cudatoolkit=11.2.2, cuda-nvcc=11.7.99 and python=3.9
```

I am running everything on windows 10 flawlessly now.

Comment: How are you using TensorFlow 2.9 on conda? Using conda search -f tensorflow returns only 2.6 and earlier versions.

Comment: It works for me tesnsorflow=2.8.1 cudnn=8.4.1.50 cudatoolkit=11.3.1 cuda-nvv=11.8.89.  @OliverNicholls Tensorflow 2.9 is on conda-forge.

Comment: Thanks, it helped with tf 2.10 as well (cuda-nvcc=11.8.89)

Answer (score 3):

This always fixes it for me on Windows x64:

```
conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc
```

To check, run this:

```
(python39) C:\>ptxas.exe --version
```

And expect something like this:

```
ptxas: NVIDIA (R) Ptx optimizing assembler
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_19:00:08_Pacific_Standard_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of community adding @Zuk Levinson comment

Solves the issue by using

```
tensorflow=2.3, cudnn=7.6.5 and cudatoolkit=10.1
```