# Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2 (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

When trying to use the GPU enabled tensorflow, I run into some error messages that seem to limit my ability to run my GPU despite many success messages in the log (see below). In terms of software, I am using an Anaconda Lite environment. In terms of hardware, I have an RTX 2080 gpu. Below are the packages installed on my environment.

I am using this tensorflow approved dependency combination:
[image]

Here is the important installs, but I attached the entire conda list below.

- TensorFlow-GPU 2.4.0
- Cudnn 8.0.5
- Cudatoolkit 11.0.3

```
absl-py                   0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               11.0.3               h3f58a73_8    conda-forge
cudnn                     8.0.5.39             hfe7f257_1    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
filetype                  1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.10                     pypi_0    pypi
imageai                   2.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        3.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-resnet              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.3                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.5.1.48                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1k               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    7.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.0.1           py37haa95532_0
protobuf                  3.15.7                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                52.0.0           py37haa95532_0
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.35.3               h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.4                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
werkzeug                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

When executing code related to the ImageAI python package, I run into the following print outs. Note: there are alot of successful DLL loads, however, there are three important points of failure to note.

- Couldn't invoke ptxas.exe --version
- Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2
- Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set

Ptas:
Tried to follow some other threads and came to the conclusion that this feature appears to be in development. [Tensorflow 2.4.1 - Couldn't invoke ptxas.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623541/tensorflow-2-4-1-couldnt-invoke-ptxas-exe)

CreateProcess:
I have found threads with this error, but none in relation to tensorflow.

tf_xla_enable_xla_devices:
This is a error that is OK to ignore, per this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44683

Attached is the entire logging when a tensorflow script is called.

```
error:2021-04-04 19:16:49.100399: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.654630: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.655534: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.685778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.71GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.23GiB/s
2021-04-04 19:16:50.685800: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.696485: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.696504: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.700890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.702964: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.711373: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.714875: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.716294: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.716353: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.716572: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716942: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.71GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.23GiB/s
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716955: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:50.716962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716968: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716975: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716979: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.716992: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-04-04 19:16:50.717021: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

error:2021-04-04 19:16:51.182297: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-04-04 19:16:51.182316: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0
2021-04-04 19:16:51.182320: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N

error:2021-04-04 19:16:51.182515: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6599 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)

error:2021-04-04 19:16:51.184721: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set

error:2021-04-04 19:16:52.512582: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)

error:2021-04-04 19:16:52.527832: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.360829: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2
2021-04-04 19:16:53.360847: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:55] Couldn't invoke ptxas.exe --version

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.369627: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.369929: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Failed to launch ptxas
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.375630: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.381209: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.386810: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.391792: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.396262: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

error:2021-04-04 19:16:53.401723: E tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:283] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2

There is a whole bunch more of the same print out that I have omitted.
```

Comment: Check the workaround mentioned in similar [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33375#issuecomment-543634440). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can make sure `ptxas` is in your conda environment by running `conda install -c nvidia cuda-nvcc` It worked for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my error of `tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:287] Call to CreateProcess failed. Error code: 2, command: '"ptxas.exe" "--version"'`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after installing only the Runtime part of the Cudatoolkit (on Windows using the GUI installer).

Make sure you install the entire CUDA package (including Runtime and Development). After that, ptxas.exe should appear in your CUDA bin folder, and Tensorflow should be able to find it.

Comment: Is the development version of CUDA available in Anaconda? Or should I avoid CUDA on Anaconda and install through NVIDIA?

Comment: can't say, in my case I was not using Anaconda, and had used the Cudatoolkit fom Nvidia

Comment: OK I'll look into that thank you for responding!

Comment: I also had this issue (also on Windows) and in my case I updated (installed a newer) graphics driver thereby removing the default driver installed with the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was:

- Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
- Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
- This message will be only logged once

and the following command worked for me

```
    conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit-dev
```